# Can a web api attribute return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am currently doing some authorization in a web api. I have created a custom AuthorizeAttribute as follows :-

```
   public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

}

}
```

Now in the HandleUnauthorizedRequest i am validation my token. The token  contains a user object. What i want is to return the decryted user object to the web api controller as below: -

```
      [HttpPost()]
        [HttpOptions]
        [CustomAuthorization]
        public PolicyListReturnType GetPolicyList(PolicyListTypeDto listTypeDto)
        {
//Get user object here;
}
```

Is this a good method or is there another way of doing this.

Comment: Authorisated user object ASP.NET stores in
`User.Identity` object

Comment: or 
   `using (UserPrincipal user
            = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context,
                                            User.Identity.Name ))`